# Remove spaces/tabs from end of line?

Tags: sed, bsd

I am trying to remove any black spaces from the end of lines. I am doing this and I am wondering why it is not working.

```
sed -i '' 's/\s*$/ endOfLine/g' myFile
```

I get this

```
MyLine
endOfLine
MyLine
endOfLine
```

I expect this

```
MyLine endOfLine
MyLine endOfLine
```

Comment: seems like DOS line endings. Check with `cat -vet myFile` . If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then run `dos2unix myFile` and try your code again. (the trailing `g` is redundant when you are anchoring your search to the end of the line). Also, I don't think `sed` honors `\s` for white-space (unless maybe  you can use a -P (for perl) option). Just use `s/[[:space:]][[:space]]*$/ endOfLIne/` . Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. "dos2unix myFile" was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I am having an issue though. My script is run every x mins in crontab. Running my script manually as root works fine, but the cron doesn't appear to be running the dos2unix command. Any ideas?

Comment: Please learn to use S.O. as a resource of existing Q/A. Searching for `[linux] script not working in cron` shows over 100 Q/A. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks but I just figured it out. I had to specify the dos2unix location in the command like this "/usr/local/bin/dos2unix myFile"